# How can I print lines from file backwards (without using "tac")?

Tags: shell, text-processing

I want to print lines from a file backwards without using `tac` command. Is there any other solution to do such thing with bash?

Answer (score 46):

Using `sed` to emulate `tac`:

```
sed '1!G;h;$!d' "${inputfile}"
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but some explanation for how this works will be even better.

Comment: It's a famous `sed` one-liner. See "36. Reverse order of lines (emulate "tac" Unix command)." in [Famous Sed One-Liners Explained](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/sed-one-liners-explained-part-one/) for a full explanation of how it works.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting:
"These two one-liners actually use a lot of memory because they keep the whole file in hold buffer in reverse order before printing it out. Avoid these one-liners for large files."

Comment: So do all the other answers (except maybe the one using `sort` - there's a chance it will use a temporary file).

Comment: This becomes *impractically slow* for not-small files... it basically *grinds to halt* ...

Comment: @Peter: Personally I'd use `tac`.

Comment: @Johnsyweb.  Yes, so would I :) but the question and answers have served to highlight tac's amazing performance. `tac` is faster, by an *order of magnitude*, than the only other *reliable* answer `cat -n | sort -nrk1 | cut -f2-` .. The non-sort/non-tac methods run into critical memory problems for large files.  Olympic *gold* for *tac*!

Comment: Note that tac is faster for regular files  because it reads the file backward. For pipes, it has to do the same as the other solutions (hold in memory or in temp files), so is not significantly faster.

Comment: This would take orders of magnitude longer to run than the `decorate (add line numbers) | sort (in reverse by line numbers) | undecorate (remove line numbers)` solutions, https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9357/133219 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/36191/133219.

Comment: Yup. This 10-year-old answer was not written as a recommendation. `tac` was written for a reason.

Answer (score 11):

With `ed`:

```
ed -s infile <<IN
g/^/m0
,p
q
IN
```

If you're on `BSD`/`OSX` (and hopefully [soon](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2014-10/msg00068.html) on `GNU`/`linux` too as [it will be POSIX](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=877)):

```
tail -r infile
```

Answer (score 9):

`awk '{a[i++]=$0} END {for (j=i-1; j>=0;) print a[j--] }' file.txt`

via [awk one liners](http://www.pement.org/awk/awk1line.txt)

Comment: A shorter one: `awk 'a=$0RS a{}END{printf a}'`

Comment: @ninjalj: it may be shorter, but it becomes **extremely** slow as the file size gets larger. I gave up after waiting for 2min 30sec. `but your first `perl reverse<>` it the best/fastest answer on the page (to me), at 10 times faster than this `awk` answer (all the awk anseres are about the same, time-wise)

Comment: Or `awk '{a[NR]=$0} END {while (NR) print a[NR--]}'`

Comment: @ninjalj appending to a variable is one of the slowest operations in awk because awk has to calculate the resulting size, find new memory, move the contents there, and change the variable to point to that new location. Doing that with a large string isn't tenable. Also never do `printf a` for any input data as it'll fail when that data contains printf formatting strings, always do `printf "%s", a` instead.

Comment: @ninjalj what does the `a{}` part do. normally `{}` contains some command, here it is, however, empty?

Comment: @AlexanderCska https://catonmat.net/awk-one-liners-explained-part-two number 35 explains it.

Comment: @MarkMcKinstry this I understand, I wanted to know how `awk 'a=$0RS a{}END{printf a}'` works

Comment: I got it. `awk 'a=$0RS a{}END{printf a}'` just concatinates all lines into a big string.  `awk '{a=$0"\n"a} END{printf a}'` would be the more transparent alternative. The new line is needed to get the proper format. Otherwise, everything will be printed on one line.

Answer (score 6):

You can pipe it through:

```
awk '{print NR" "$0}' | sort -k1 -n -r | sed 's/^[^ ]* //g'
```

The `awk` prefixes each line with the line number followed by a space. The `sort` reverses the order of the lines by sorting on the first field (line number) in reverse order, numeric style. And the `sed` strips off the line numbers.

The following example shows this in action:

```
pax$ echo 'a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
k
l' | awk '{print NR" "$0}' | sort -k1 -n -r | sed 's/^[^ ]* //g'
```

It outputs:

```
l
k
j
i
h
g
f
e
d
c
b
a
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks!  I'll try this. And thanks for the comments!

Comment: `cat -n` acts much like `awk '{print NR" "$0}'`

Comment: I think that's called **Schwartzian transform**, or **decorate-sort-undecorate**

Comment: This general approach is nice in that sort handles using files on disk if the task is too big to reasonably do in memory.  It might be gentler on memory though if you used temporary files between the steps rather than pipes.

Comment: @ChenLevy yes but `-n` isn't one of the POSIX options for `cat`, see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cat.html, so `cat -n` isn't as portable as `awk '{print NR, $0}'`.

Comment: `awk -v OFS='\t' '{print NR, $0}' file | sort -k1,1nr | cut -f2-` is IMHO the cleanest way to write that as it's still using mandatory POSIX tools but is using awks OFS instead of hard-coding a separator char in the print and doing string concatenation, is using awk to generate input that uses the default separator for cut, `\t`, is using `cut` for it's sole purpose instead of making `sed` do what `cut` exists to do, and is only sorting on the one, necessary field that contains the line number.

Answer (score 6):

As you asked to do it in bash, here is a solution that doesn't make use of awk, sed or perl, just a bash function:

```
reverse ()
{
    local line
    if IFS= read -r line
    then
        reverse
        printf '%s\n' "$line"
    fi
}
```

The output of

```
echo 'a
b
c
d
' | reverse
```

is

```
d
c
b
a
```

As expected.

But beware that lines are stored in memory, one line in each recursively called instance of the function. So careful with big files.

Comment: It quickly becomes impractically slow as file size increases, compared to even the slowest of the other answers, and as you have suggested, it blows memory pretty easily: *bash recursive function...  but its an interesting idea.
Segmentation fault
*

Answer (score 2):

POSIX vi does this, so also ed or ex.

vi:

```
:g/^/m0
```

ex:

```
ex -s infile <<EOS
g/^/move0
x
EOS
```

ed:

```
ed -s infile <<EOF
g/^/m0
,p
w
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

In perl:

```
cat <somefile> | perl -e 'while(<>) { push @a, $_; } foreach (reverse(@a)) { print; }'
```

Comment: or the shorter `perl -e 'print reverse<>'`

Comment: (Actually, there's a shorter one, but it's _really_ ugly, witness its awfulness: `perl -pe '$\=$_.$\}{'` )

Comment: @Frederik Deweerdt: Fast, but it loses the first line... @ ninjalj: `reverse<)` is fast: good!  but the "really ugly" one is **extremely slow** as the number of lines increases.!!....

Comment: @Peter.O the `-n` was superfluous there, thanks.

Comment: The nice thing about this one is that the contents of the file is not necessarily read into memory (except possibly in chunks by `sort`).

Answer (score 0):

BASH-only solution

read file into bash array ( one line = one element of array ) and print out array in reverse order:

```
i=0 

while read line[$i] ; do
    i=$(($i+1))
done < FILE


for (( i=${#line[@]}-1 ; i>=0 ; i-- )) ; do
    echo ${line[$i]}
done
```

Comment: Try it with indented lines... philfr's version is a bit better but still veeeery slooooow so really, when it comes to text processing, never use `while..read`.

Comment: Use `IFS=''` and `read -r` to prevent all kinds of escapes and trailing IFS removal from screwing it up. I think the bash `mapfile ARRAY_NAME` builtin is a better solution for reading into arrays though.

Answer (score 0):

Bash, with `mapfile` mentioned in comments to fiximan, and actually an possibly better version:

```
# last [LINES=50]
_last_flush(){ BUF=("${BUF[@]:$(($1-LINES)):$1}"); } # flush the lines, can be slow.
last(){
  local LINES="${1:-10}" BUF
  ((LINES)) || return 2
  mapfile -C _last_flush -c $(( (LINES<5000) ? 5000 : LINES+5 )) BUF
  BUF=("${BUF[@]}") # Make sure the array subscripts make sence, can be slow.
  ((LINES="${#BUF[@]}" > LINES ? LINES : "${#BUF[@]}"))
  for ((i="${#BUF[@]}"; i>"${#BUF[@]}"-LINES; i--)); do echo -n "${BUF[i]}"; done
}
```

Its performance is basically comparable to the `sed` solution, and gets faster as the number of requested lines decreases.

Answer (score 0):

```
Simple do this with your file to sort the data in reverse order, and it should be unique.
```

> sed -n '1h;1d;G;h;$p'

Answer (score 0):

- Number the lines with nl
- sort in reverse order by number
- remove the numbers with sed

as shown here:

```
echo 'e
> f
> a
> c
> ' | nl -ba | sort -nr | sed -r 's/^ *[0-9]+\t//'
```

Result:

> ```
> c
> a
> f
> e
> ```

Note that "nl -ba" for including empty lines in the numbering is an option of GNU-nl and might not work with every nl.

Comment: `nl` does not number blank lines. There is already another answer implementing this Schwartzian transform idea.

Comment: You're right, nl needs the option `-ba` for empty lines and might not exist for every `nl`.

Comment: `nl` isn't a mandatory POSIX tool so iif you don't have `tac` you probably don't have `nl` either.

Answer (score -1):

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{ print NR,$0 }' | sort -nr | cut -f 2-
```

This prepends the line number before each line, with a delimiting tab character, sorts the lines in reverse order on these line numbers, and then removes the numbers again with `cut`.

See also: [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) (Wikipedia link)

Comment: I assume this got downvoted because it's essentially the same answer as was posted a year earlier at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9357/133219.