# How to insert text after the last configuration line?

Tags: text-processing, replace

I have to insert a line into a configuration files automatically, but with the added caveat that it should be inserted *before* a multi-line footer comment and any preceding empty or whitespace-only lines *if the footer exists*. That is, **the new line should be inserted right after the last configuration line**, making for a single-line diff from the original file. In pseudo-code:

1. Go to the end of the file.
2. Go backwards to the first (that is, last in the file) configuration line (that is, a line which is not empty, whitespace-only, comment only or whitespace followed by a comment).
3. Insert text after the current line.

Extended regular expression for configuration line: `^\s*[^[:space:]#]`

Any common *nix tools such as `sed`, `awk`, `ed` or `ex` should work.

---

Possible solutions and their problems:

- Use [`tac`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/742485/96588) twice to make this into a forward-searching problem rather than backward-searching. This means I'll have to store the result in a temporary file then replace the original, rather than doing this in a single command.
- Use `sed -i` with the [reversal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9356/how-can-i-print-lines-from-file-backwards-without-using-tac) trick. This means storing the entire file in memory.
- `ex -c '1' -c '?^\s*[^[:space:]#]?' -c $'a\nmy new line\n.' -c 'wq' /path`, which I'm also given to understand stores the full file in memory.

Is there a solution which circumvents both of these issues?

Example starting file:

```
# Universe configuration
#

pi = 3 # A good #
e = mc**2 # To within a hair

[cut 200 trillion lines]

# 
# END
#
```

Example input:

```
sol { mass = 42, start = 9.2 }
```

Expected output:

```
# Universe configuration
#

pi = 3 # A good #
e = mc**2 # To within a hair

[cut 200 trillion lines]
sol { mass = 42, start = 9.2 }

# 
# END
#
```

[General-purpose function](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/commit/2b2aaee37619da9f11beeb6af2ac55beb62668b7) based on [@StephaneChazelas's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/78573/3645)

Comment: `^\s*[^#]` matches "<space>#", you want `^\s*[^\s#]` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something along these lines:

```
file=/some/file
newtext='sol { mass = 42, start = 9.2 }'
tac -- "$file" | 
  NEWTEXT=$newtext awk -v size="$(wc -c < "$file")" '
    $1 ~ /^[^#]/ {
      system("dd bs=1 seek=" size - length(footer) " conv=notrunc if=/dev/null")
      printf "%s\n%s", ENVIRON["NEWTEXT"], footer
      exit
    }
    {footer=$0 "\n" footer}' 1<> "$file"
```

That overwrites the file in place and only stores the footer in memory. It needs the non-standard GNU `tac` command. The file has to be a regular text file.

Comment: Wow. My single `ex` command is almost three times slower than this, even on a 267 *byte* file.

Comment: I think `ex` is not the solution, it must read the whole file before execute command.

Comment: @l0b0, for such a short file, the difference is only going to be due to the loading time of the utilities. Note that `ex` will need to read the whole file, but not store the whole content in memory (though it  will still need to store a fair amount of information in memory). YMMV depending on the `ex` implementation.

Comment: Sure, I was just surprised that the startup time of `ex` (even when reading the file) was much more than the combined startup time of `tac`, `awk` and `dd` plus a subshell.

Comment: @l0b0, your `ex` sounds like `vim`. If it's the `vim` with gnome support, it probably pulls gigabytes of library dependencies. There may be some plugin loading from vim files as well.

Comment: PS: Works with GNU `awk` 3.1.4, but not with `mawk` 1.2. No output, and no changes to the file.

Comment: Ah, thanks @StephaneChazelas. I assumed `ex` would load with minimal dependencies.

Comment: @l0b0, it looks the library up and mmaps them, but do not load the code except the init section of the libraries it doesn't use. Use the `-s`  option to minimise the impact. gigabytes was a bit of an exageration.

Comment: @l0b0, `mawk` doesn't support POSIX character classes, you can use `[ \t]` there.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` only solution (tested with gawk):

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN   {   footer = ""; wl = ""; } 
    END     {   while(( getline line < "sol.txt") > 0 ) {
                    print(line)
                }
                footer = wl footer
                print substr(footer, 0, length(footer)-1); 
            }

    # Blank line
    /^[[:blank:]]*$/ {
                if (footer) {
                    footer = wl footer
                    print substr(footer, 0, length(footer)-1); 
                    footer = ""
                }
                wl = $0 "\n"
            }
    # Comment only
    /^[[:blank:]]*#/ {
                footer = footer $0 "\n"; 
            }

    # Configuration line
    /^[[:blank:]]*[^[:space:]#]/ {
                print(wl footer $0); wl = ""; footer = ""; 
            }
    ' <  universe.txt > universe2.txt
```

Producing:

```
# Universe configuration
#

pi = 3 # A good #
e = mc**2 # To within a hair

[cut 200 trillion lines]
sol { mass = 42, start = 9.2 }

# 
# END
#
```

With one line diff:

```
sh$ diff universe*.txt
8d7
< sol { mass = 42, start = 9.2 }
```

Comment: This seems to simply place the text just before the last comment block, which is not the requested feature. For example, what if there are several comment blocks separated by empty lines? This also doesn't seem to handle whitespace before comment characters.

Comment: I have difficulties to understand the specification of the footer. Sorry about that. If a footer is "a sequence of zero or more white lines followed by one or more comment lines", I've modified my answer to better match your specs. But maybe a footer could be made of several comments intermixed with several blank lines?

Answer (score -1):

This is a configuration file, so it fits comfortably in memory. There is no need to process it as a stream.

```
newline='
' tab=$(echo | tr '\n' '\t')
old=$(cat foo.config)
footer=${old##*"$newline[!$newline$tab #]"}
if [ "$footer" = "$old" ]; then
  footer=
else
  footer=${footer#*"$newline"}
fi
head=${old%"$footer"}
echo "$head$text_to_insert$footer" >foo.config.new
```